# How can I target the next child elements text with Beautiful soup?

Tags: beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful Soup I am trying to extract the number highlighted in the picture below. I am able to target and ouput the entire span class  but I only want just that anchors text string

How can I tell Beautiful Soup I want the next child elements value only? I am expecting the output to be **90NBHA138J2C255D431U**

**My attempt so far**

```
target=soup.findAll('span',{'class':'data data_mpn'})
print target
```

**Image of my targeted string**
[image: Target]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
soup.find('span', id='firstProductCode').find('a').string
```